# Trouble with conditional probabilities

Tags: probability

What would be the right way (if there is any) to calculate P(A|B1 and B2 and ... Bn), given that B1...Bn are independent and we know:

- P(Bi) for i=1..n
- P(A|Bi) for i=1..n
- P(A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a really simple case. Suppose $n=2$, $p(A)=p(B_1)=p(B_2)=\frac{1}{2}$, $p(B_1\cap B_2)=\frac{1}{4}$, $p(A\cap B_1)=p(A\cap B_2)=\frac{1}{4}$. Unfortunately, that does not determine $p(A|B_1\cap B_2)$. It could, for example, be (1) 0 or (2) $\frac{1}{2}$. Draw a Venn diagram. Case (1) is achieved by having no chance of $A$ unless we have just one of $B_1,B_2$. Case (2) is achieved by the opposite - no chance of $A$ unless we have either both or neither of $B_1,B_2$.